# How to download blender manual?

Tags: documentation

How to download blender manual link on the website is dead, is it mandatory to download the repository and build the manual to have it off line?

there is no link to download the ZIP file ever, can any one enlight me about this matter plz.

Comment: you can find a zip with html files of the 2.76, and here is a link for the complete PDF of the 2.75, I don't know if it answers? ftp://ftp.blender.org/ideasman42/blender_manual.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is the 2.79 manual.  You can download it from here.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/index.html)

[This is the 2.80 manual. It is a work-in-progress.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/)

In general, you can use your favorite search engine to search for "blender 2.79 manual" replacing 2.79 with the version you are looking for.  This will usually lead to a link for that version.

Comment: That was the page I was on when I tried to download the first time and clicking on the link had no response not even a file not found message, somehow now it's working I could download it. Thanks.
ps: sorry for delay wasn't home